# Query & date formatting

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I have run into an issue where I have a query formula that acts like a filter on multiple criteria. I have been trying to add into it the ability to search between dates as well, with intermittent success. I used it awhile back and I had the date bit working, but now it is not! I'm convinced it's to do with formatting, but I'm unsure. I've tried various solutions I found on the internet to do with DATEVALUE and TEXT to amend the value for query, but I am struggling and hoping a fresh pair of eyes can see the issue? The issue is at end of formula with column D.

`=IFERROR(query(testimport!A:R,"Select *" & IF((left(M6,1))="*","Where C starts with '"& RIGHT(M6,LEN(M6)-1) &"' and A contains '"&$A6&"' and B contains '"&$B6&"' and C contains '"&$C6&"' and E contains '"&$E6&"' and F contains '"&$F6&"' and G contains '"&$G6&"' and L contains '"&$L6&"' and N contains '"&$N6&"' and O contains '"&$O6&"' and P contains '"&$P6&"' and Q contains '"&$Q6&"' and R contains '"&$R6&"'","Where A contains '"&$A6&"' and B contains '"&$B6&"' and C contains '"&$C6&"' and E contains '"&$E6&"' and F contains '"&$F6&"' and G contains '"&$G6&"' and L contains '"&$L6&"' and N contains '"&$N6&"' and O contains '"&$O6&"' and P contains '"&$P6&"' and Q contains '"&$Q6&"' and R contains '"&$R6&"' and D >= '"&$S1&"' and D <= '"&$T1&"'"),1),)`

Google sheet link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19myFaD1OlYKDjRJkV_OQFFcN8nfkYbur7mHioUk_Wco/edit?usp=sharing

I've tried the methods in below links..

https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/how-to-use-date-criteria-in-query-function-in-google-sheets/

https://www.benlcollins.com/spreadsheets/query-dates/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're right that this is a date format issue.

On a quick look, when you test `27/07/2019 > 01/08/2019` the result is `TRUE`
However when `01/08/2019 > 5/08/2019` is tested you have the expected `FALSE`
When `=DATEDIF(L8,L9,"d")` is tested or `Date A - Date B`  there's the expected `5` result.

So when I input the data myself (`27/07/2019 > 01/08/2019`) there's a false. That is the good behavior.

You just need to format your dates on column `D`. 
Take `D` column and use a different date format with the `More Formats` option.

[Here's the mess I made to find out.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1B-dlr6VRl2PkHDksijC411Wd8qorrD5h1wNMF3n6x_8/edit?usp=sharing)

Another way to format this column:
Try this formula `=DATE(YEAR(D1),month(D1),day(D1))` where `D1` is obviously the date with a weird format.

Comment: Hi PaulJ, thanks for looking into this. The query isn't working on your copy and is display 27/07/2019 when 01/08/2019 is in the input cell...is this intended?

Comment: Thanks, I've taken onboard all your experiments and relooked at some solutions and adding Col4 >= date '"&TEXT(S1,"yyyy-mm-dd")& does the trick! this date formatting is maddening lol!

Comment: I must confess i was out of ideas, i'm glad you resolved it. 
I still didn't quite understood what is the issue here with the formatting, it doesn't make sens. 
Have a great day.

Comment: Well, turns out weirdly that Query language only accepts date in one format which is YYYY-MM-DD in text format, but you need to specify the date clause in the query syntax.

Comment: This explain the "date" string in the Query. Glad to learn that today because it could have been a serious issues in the futur when messing with date. 
I found this material for further explanation and use-cases https://www.benlcollins.com/spreadsheets/query-dates/
Have a great day.