# Using a query on an importrange, not pulling information

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-dates

I am trying to do a query on `importrange` but it is only showing me the headers not any of the data. I am really stuck.

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("19Nx2EtMktFW-xwNMjY4IiQpN33QHrXIwcqDsvKqCiHo", "MASTER!A1:F300"),"SELECT * where Col3='8/1/2019'")
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Query & date formatting](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/132427/query-date-formatting)